# I jumped my Saturn Compressor - still not engaging

Tags: clutch, saturn, compressor

I jumped my Saturn compressor right to the battery but the clutch did not click nor engage. what does this mean?  I also used the paper clip trick with the low pressure switch and it only turns on the cooling fan but the clutch does not engage  the compressor.  what now?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If the clutch doesn't engage with what you've tried, I'd suggest the clutch solenoid is shot.

Comment: Replace the whole compressor, or the clutch assembly if you can find a new one sold separately.

Comment: What compressor is this? Some compressors feature OEM coils equipped with a thermal fuse that trips at certain temperature (such as 187°C). Low refrigerant can overheat the compressor and make this fuse trip. If you can manage to get the drive belt off and remove your compressor yourself, go to some place with a refrigerant recovery station, ask to have the system evacuated and after you've got the compressor off you can either replace the thermal fuse with one of the same value, or the entire coil yourself. Before removing the compressor, first check coil resistance (with multimeter) though.

Comment: If you have correct coil resistance (between 3 and 6 Ohms) and the coil is powered, the operating gap may be too large and the clutch assembly may have to be reshimmed.